How do I download Java runtime/JRE more recent than version 8
Simple question, with an example: I want to launch the minecraft server...
Download: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
Run cmd: java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.21.4.jar nogui
Error: Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.1.21.4.jar
Rename server.jar to minecraft_server.1.21.4.jar and re-run.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Oh dear, I have an old version of java. From https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/,
Java 8  52.0
...
Java 23 67.0

No problem. Let me just google "download java" and grab the latest...

https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp
https://www.java.com/en/download/

Oh, good, these both promise the most recent.

Version 8 Update 431 (filesize: 66.03 MB) Why is Java 8 recommended?
Release date: October 15, 2024

Aah.. what?? Version 8 was released in like 2014. You sure about that Oracle? But seriously, what on earth is going on here?
Anyway, I download and install these and sure enough it's java 8 and minecraft still won't run. I have seen that there are JDKs for higher versions availble:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
Lol thanks, Oracle /s, I don't want to develop a java app. I just want to run it :). Where can I download JRE 21?

Link-only answer: possible reasons here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111921/how-can-i-get-java-11-run-time-environment-working-since-there-is-no-more-jre-11 - quick fix was to install OpenJDK_JRE instead from https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/ (scroll to Windows x64, grab the JRE .msi installer)


Where can I download JRE 21?

Oracle no longer distributes a Java Environment Runetime (JRE). To install and run a newer version of Java, you need to download JDK 21. The Java Environment Runtime (JRE) is contained within the Java Development Kit.

Java version 8 was released in 2014.

Oracle actually still maintains Java 8 here. Just having Java 8 is enough to run the most recent version of Minecraft. If you are still having a problem, I suggest migrating to Minecraft on the Windows Store. You might find Minecraft: Bedrock Edition is a more capable version than Minecraft: Java Edition.

Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.1.21.4.jar

This error is due to you having multiple versions of Java installed. You must use the fully qualified path to the correct Java environment. You shouldn’t have to rename the file in order to run it.

@jozxyqk - If Minecraft is unable to locate your Java installation with JDK 21 installed then that’s a system configuration issue. JDK 21 absolutely contains what you need to run a Java application that supports the Java Runtime version 65. Minecraft at one time supported Java 8 it mostly likely no requires Java 21+, the Minecraft website in that regard, is clear as dirt.

I hadn't installed the Java Development Kit (JDK) since I'm not a developer - I just wanted the runtime to run the minecraft server. I'm curious if it would have worked out of the box or needed further setup. As it is the adoptium.net solution has worked for now. Agreed!

I submitted this answer to indicate that the JDK 21 would have installed the JRE.
